# How to check if a field contains round braces?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a very large flat-file list which I have been able to parse with a novice knowledge of awk but I'm running into a bit of a learning curve when my fields are not separated by spaces and not quite uniform. My sample data is as follows:

```
AAA 10(05/12)(06:59) BBB
CCC 12       (12:24) DDD
EEE 10 04:39 (02:10) FFF
GGG 13 12/09  03:52  HHH
```

I want to parse out the fields from the 3rd column, but only if they are not blank nor surrounded by parenthesis. So I should have an output of 4 lines, 2 blanks and 2 filled with data:

```
*blank*
*blank*
04:39
12/09
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
my loop:
dtime=substr($0,7,7)
if (match(dtime,"(\\(.*\\))")==1) {
    dtime=""
}
print dtime
```

Is there more efficient way to do this?

Comment: why does you output contain blanks if you don't want them.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to display "blank rows" on this site. Basically my output, when blanks are found, comes back with a 7 character blank string.

Comment: You *want* those blank rows?

Answer (score 2):

Try gawk [`FIELDWIDTHS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size) variable:

```
# AAA 10(05/12)(06:59) BBB
# .3.1.21.5...11..5..11.3.
$ gawk -vFIELDWIDTHS='3 1 2 1 5 1 1 5 1 1 3' '{if($4=="(" && $6==")")print ""; else print $5}' input 


04:39
12/09
```

Comment: That was my first thought too, but sadly our client's machines (where this script will be running) do not have gawk available. Just awk.

Comment: You can run through `sed` to convert it to `csv` file firstly.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -e 's/[^ ]* *[^( ]*//'                          \
    -e 's/[(]*[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][)]* *...$//'    \
    -e 's/(.*)//' input
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you:

```
$ awk 'NF==5{print $3;next}{print "*blank*"}' file
*blank*
*blank*
04:39
12/09
```